# Simple query performance on 300M row table is very slow even with beefy hardware

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-performance

**Hardware/PostgreSQL version:**

AWS RDS db.r4.xlarge (4vCPU, 30.5GB RAM, Provisioned IOPS (SSD) storage, 2500 IOPS)

PostgreSQL version 11.

**Background:**

I have an ever-growing table that I feel isn't anywhere near as performant as it should be.

With around 300M rows and growing by ~4M a month, the table looks as follows:

```
(
    proprietary_id text,
    date date,
    instance_id text,
    title text,
    type text,
    earnings numeric(19,6),
    date_paid date,
    report_type text,
    state text,
    user_type text,
    platform_type text
)
```

The fields that are of type `text` have no real standard from the data source, so this is a frustrating but necessary generic data type.

I have indexes on `proprietary_id` (the main identifier for a given row) and `date_paid`

A simple query like:

```
select sum(earnings) from "my-slow-table" where date_paid = '2020-04-01'
```

Takes over **7 minutes** to run. Just about every query on this table, regardless of complexity (within reason) seems to take this long. I am by no means a DB expert, but I have just enough experience to get myself in trouble with you all here thinking "I've done what I should do to make this thing faster". `VACUUM ANALYZE` has been ran on this bad boy after any large insert/update/delete as well as 15 minutes before posting this.

**Question:**

What else could I try to speed things up? I know I could start partitioning, but I feel like this performance is abysmal from researching query times of much larger tables online - we don't even come close to maxing resources on the RDS instance itself so perhaps there's some postgres configuration that needs to happen to improve things?

Please forgive me if this is a silly question or has a simple answer - I've just exhausted my knowledge to this point. Happy to learn and looking for resources to expand my knowledge!

**PS**

Here's the long query plan output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (which I need to get much better at fully understanding):

**EDIT 1**

Replaced with `FORMAT TEXT` instead of the JSON format

```
"Finalize Aggregate  (cost=6872714.58..6872714.59 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=415295.495..415295.496 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Gather  (cost=6872714.36..6872714.57 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=415291.983..415296.893 rows=3 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=6871714.36..6871714.37 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=415291.643..415291.644 rows=1 loops=3)"
"              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on "my-slow-table"  (cost=0.00..6860703.50 rows=4404341 width=4) (actual time=194857.517..413608.182 rows=3663864 loops=3)"
"                    Filter: (date_paid = '2020-08-01'::date)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 68302664"
"Planning Time: 0.114 ms"
"Execution Time: 415296.963 ms"
```

**EDIT 2**

And here's the same explain after confirming both indexes on `proprietary_id` and `date_paid` **AND** setting `enable_seqscan = off;`:

```
"Finalize Aggregate  (cost=7170994.77..7170994.78 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=19354.251..19354.252 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Gather  (cost=7170994.55..7170994.76 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=19353.345..19357.306 rows=3 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=7169994.55..7169994.56 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=19350.550..19350.551 rows=1 loops=3)"
"              ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on "my-slow-table"  (cost=197953.32..7158983.69 rows=4404341 width=4) (actual time=541.486..17691.885 rows=3663864 loops=3)"
"                    Recheck Cond: (date_paid = '2020-08-01'::date)"
"                    Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 579438"
"                    Heap Blocks: exact=19364 lossy=86080"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "my-slow-table-date-paid-idx"  (cost=0.00..195310.71 rows=10570419 width=0) (actual time=529.688..529.689 rows=10991594 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: (date_paid = '2020-08-01'::date)"
"Planning Time: 0.121 ms"
"Execution Time: 19357.390 ms"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a sequential scan where 19 out of 20 rows are discarded by the filter. Clearly you are missing a simple index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON "my-slow-table" (date_paid);
```

Oh, you already have that index, and it is used to the advantage of execution time if you disable sequential scans!

Then the reason why PostgreSQL chooses to avoid the index scan must be that `work_mem` is set so low that an effective, non-degenerated bitmap that contains a bit per table row won't fit. So it has to resort to a"lossy" bitmap, where some bits stand for a whole page, which leads to extra work and makes the plan unattractive.

Increase `work_mem`, and the optimizer will be more happy to choose the index scan, which will be even faster. While at it, review your setting for `random_page_cost` and `effective_cache_size` to see if they reflect the reality of your hardware, so that the optimizer's cost estimates teflect the actual costs better.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the case - I have indexes on both date_paid and proprietary_id

Comment: Hard to believe. What happens if you `SET enable_seqscan = off;` before running the query?

Comment: I edited the original question to reflect the explain analyze output after setting `enable_seqscan = off;` which had huge results. So the question is why is the query planner choosing to use seq scan when the indexes indeed exist? Also, thank you very much for your help so far

Comment: I think that makes the case clear, see my extended answer.

Comment: Initial tests are showing that this is likely pushing me in the direction of a solution. Setting those parameters like you said within a single session have made the query planner start using index scans instead of seq scans. Marking this as answered. Thank you Laurenz!

Answer (score 2):

You can encourage the use of the indexes by lowering random_page_cost to only slightly higher than seq_page_cost.  The default is 4 (unless RDS made custom changes to it) while 1.1 is probably better for provisioned IOPS.

Also, making work_mem larger, to get rid of lossy blocks, should improve the performance, but I don't think it changes the estimate and so won't encourage it to use the index over the seq scan in the first place.

The ideal index for the query you show would be on `(date_paid, earnings)`.  This could use an index-only scan which should be much faster than the bitmap scan

Comment: Yes I've seen quite a but about random_page_cost and the impact - I changed this as well and still no dice on getting this table to use this index. It uses `proprietary_id` just fine, but of course these are much more varying - `date_paid` is locked to the first of the month always i.e. `2020-07-01`. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Could the issue be related to the 8 text columns and how the database is accessing the rows?  I have not delved into innards of postgresql, but if the widths cannot be reliably estimated, doesn't that force the server to slog through the table row by row?  I think @jjanes recommendation on the index might be the right solution.

Comment: If you lower random_page_cost to less seq_page_cost (maybe even to zero) does that switch the plan to use the index?  That is not practical solution, just a test to see what is going on.  Probably you table is pretty well clustered on date_paid, and bitmap heap scans don't get enough "credit" for operating on clustered tables.